# using one div as a target for another javascript

Tags: javascript

okay so I'm trying to make a pinbar for bookmarking and this of that sort. Right now, I'm trying to add in a sort of drop off circle used to add items into the pinbar. I've made all the items that go into the pinbar draggable with specific targets. I don't know how to make the "drop off" circle a target, but to have the items still pushed into the pinbar rather than stuck inside the circle.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="page" data-draggable="target">
            <!-- bubbles on page -->
            <ul data-draggable="target" id="dataList">
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud4"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud4"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud4"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud4"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud3"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud2"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud1"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud1"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud1"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud1"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud1"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud1"></li>
                <li data-draggable="item" class="testbud" id="testbud1"></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tabs"> 
                <div class="tab-item active"><a href="#" data-target="#tab-1">Pinned</a> 
                </div>
                <div class="tab-item">
                    <a  href="#" data-target="#tab-2" id="recentTab">Recent</a>
                </div>
                <div  class="tab-pane">
                    <div class="tab-content active" id="tab-1" data-draggable="target"></div>
                    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-2" data-draggable="target">
                        <div class="rpin-container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
    for (var items = document.querySelectorAll('[data-draggable="item"]'),len = items.length, i = 0; i < len;i++) {
        items[i].setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    }
    var item = null;
    document.addEventListener("dragstart",function(e) {
        item = e.target;
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text", "");
    },false);
    document.addEventListener("dragover",function(e) {
        if (item) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },false);
    document.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
        if (e.target.getAttribute("data-draggable") == "target") {
            e.target.appendChild(item);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },false);
    document.addEventListener("dragend", function(e) {
        item = null;
    },false);
})();
```

link to the codepen "https://codepen.io/eduardo_r/pen/eLKLLm"

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking for help with. Playing with your codepen, it looks like it works fine as far as dragging and dropping items into the pinbar. Can you please clarify your problem description with expected behavior? I'm not able to find your described drop off circle, nor am I able to see anything stuck inside of it.

Comment: @ggorlen We want to add something like a circle with a plus sign for example that would sit inside of the pinbar. We want it to work so that you drop something into the circle and it drops not inside of the circle but into the pinbar next to it